# Dealing with a ton of output on Chrome web dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm debugging an app that is spitting out a huge amount of output that I'm viewing in Chrome's JS console. I only want at tiny bit of it, but it's totally choking up. Is there a way to pause a tab's JS execution (or just pause new things being written to the log), or export the logs to a plaintext editor that'll handle it a bit better?

(For what it's worth, I'm debugging JS that's generated by GWT.)

Comment: are you using breakpoints in the js that is outputting?

Comment: Ah looks like there's a "pause script execution" button under the "Scripts" tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a breakpoint by clicking the line number where you want script execution to stop.  Or you can click the pause button to stop script execution immediately:

[image: How to pause Chrome JavaScript]